# Javascript splice method issue

Tags: javascript, splice

I have a problem with the splice method. In the script below, if I set the second argument of splice to '0' it crashes my browser. If I set to any other value that is greater than '0' it works just fine.

Why is this happening?

Thanks,

And the code:

```
function f (x) {

    var d = x.toString().split("");

    for (i=0; i<d.length; i++){
        if (Number(d[i])%2===0){
            d.splice(i, 0, "drum");
        }
    } 

    return d;
};
```

Comment: which browser u testing? and what is the value of x?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome. x is 888.

Comment: Once the condition is true, you insert an element at the beginning of the list, causing the next iteration to repeat for the same element, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Rob W, I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an infinite loop and each time `drum` is getting inserted to array increasing its length.

`Splice()` insert the item to array so you are inserting new item.

first loop:

- Array is `8,8,8`
- `i` is 0 //d[0] is 8
- Condition `if (Number(d[i])%2===0)` is `true`
- `drum` inserted Now Array is `drum,8,8,8`

second loop:

- Array is `drum,8,8,8`
- `i` is 1 //d[i] is 8
- Condition `if (Number(d[i])%2===0)` is `true`
- `drum` inserted Now Array is `drum,drum,8,8,8`

and it goes on....